# NetBeans - How to import a class from an external library

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.7, weka

I have a Java project in Netbeans and I want to use some classes from **Weka** within my project.

I added the file C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7\weka-src.jar into my Libraries following the instructions [here](http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/) (project, properties, libraries ..)

So how do I now import the classes I want?

I tried importing like this:

```
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
```

And for kicks, I also tried this which didn't work either:

```
import src.main.java.weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
```

NetBeans says "package does not exist" for both.

Have I linked the libraries incorrectly?  Do I need to phrase the import differently?

Much thanks for any insight into this you can provide.

**Update:**

In my Libraries folder of my projects tab I see:

weka-src.jar and under that I see: , META-INF, lib, src.main.java.weka.associations, and lots of other things from weka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have downloaded Weka from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-7-windows/3.7.2/weka-3-7-2.exe/download). I have added the JAR file you mentioned and I have also added weka-src.jar.

The problem is that although I have no problems with your first import:

```
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
```

I can't see this package anywhere:

```
import src.main.java.weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
```

To see if you have successfully imported a .jar file or a library, click on the "Projects" button on the left margin, find the Project you have added the resource to and expand the view (by pressing the + sign). You should have an item named "Libraries". If you expand that, you should be able to see the files you have added.

Comment: I do see it under that libraries folder.  I updated my question to describe what I see.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you have to also add weka.jar

Comment: Hmm I'll try that.  Out of curiousity, why do I need both?

Comment: If I remeber correctly, the first import you are using lies within weka.jar, whilst the second one, even though it does not seem to exist in the weka-src.jar file, has a very similar stucture to the items found in weka-src.jar

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for how to install Weka Jar file too, and I read this tutorial and I realize that the jar file is actually on you Weka installer, and then you just need to import the jar file as same as any other library. Take a chance to look this tutorial, it is pretty cool.

http://www.cs.umb.edu/~ding/history/480_697_spring_2013/homework/WekaJavaAPITutorial.pdf

"Logic will take you from point A to point B, imagination will take you everywhere"